# Gestion des configurations

Tags: abréviations

This seems a little long winded, and I don't have much space.  Though Setup Manager in English isn't a lot shorter.  Is there a good abbreviation for Gestion des configurations?

Is there another way to say Setup Manager?

**Update**:

I suppose I should say this is for clients that can be intelligent just not computer savvy.

Comment: Maybe this should have been asked: why an abbreviation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Gestion* could be abbreviated to *Gest.* and *configurations* to *config.*.

You could omit *des*.

So the ultimate abbreviation would be *Gest. config.* but I would rather use *Gestion des config.* if possible.

Another solution is to use *Configurations* alone (it's obviously to manage them).

Comment: configuration, ou config est effectivement le plus simple et évident.

Comment: La gestion des configurations est une activité spécifique qui ne traite pas directement des configurations elles-mêmes, mais de l'administration des différentes révisions de ces configurations, leur archivage, leur cohérence, la comparaison entre différentes versions, des rapports, etc. Supprimer « gestion » enlève ce sens.

Comment: @jlliagre - les "informaticiens" tendent à être mauvais pour ce qui est de nommer les choses correctement, et aussi à s'habituer à de mauvais noms,  qu'ils perpétuent ensuite ... et cela a au moins deux raisons: d'une part le vocabulaire vient souvent de l'anglais, et il peut être difficile de traduire, ou bien l'on utilise les mots anglais directement ; d'autre part, l'informatique devient un domaine ouvert à beaucoup d'individus, dont nombre ne se soucient pas vraiment d'utiliser _le bont mot_ (malheureusement) ...

Comment: @Frank J'ai du mal à voir le rapport avec mon commentaire. Ici « gestion » et « configurations » ne sont pas des termes particulièrement anglais.

Comment: @jlliagre - j'ai simplement tenté d'expliquer pourquoi l'on voit beaucoup de noms mal choisis en info. J'allais dans votre sens en fait.

Comment: @Frank Ah bon, ce n'était pas évident. *By the way*: https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37/est-ce-quon-se-tutoie

Answer (score 1):

In my work environment we frequently say "GConf" (pronounced like "*j'ai conf* ") as a abreviation for **G**estion de **Conf**iguration, but this is more an oral usage. If you work with native speakers and with people used to work in a software development environment, I have no doubt they will understand what GConf means.

Comment: gconf n'a rien d'évident -1

Comment: @guillaumegirod-vitouchkina à première vue non, et je ne peux pas vous l'opposer. Ensuite ça devient évident. Au pire la discussion suivante aura lieu :"il faut mettre ca sous GConf ; - GConf ? ; - Gestion de configuration ; and voila

Comment: @guillaumegirod-vitouchkina J'ai plussoyé cette réponse car je suis d'accord avec le_daim. GConf est bien déjà utilisé et facilement compris comme abréviation de gestion de configuration en informatique en France : http://fr.viadeo.com/fr/groups/detaildiscussion/?containerId=00211puqrkwvx3nj&action=messageDetail&messageId=0021ul45lwd5b2cw http://ristretto.weave.eu/2012/06/25/role-dindicateurs-qualite-dans-le-processus-de-gestion-de-la-configuration-gconf/  http://phr-configuration.com/formations-et-iso-15288/ http://www.eurogiciel.fr/notre-groupe/nos-references/

Comment: gconf? gnu conf? depending on what you are doing in CS, it might not be readily understood. If you work in Java, you might not work with gnu stuff at all.

Comment: Ou Gnome conf? So there you have it: even inside of software engineering, "gconf" is ambiguous. So, I don't think we can recommend it as a good abbreviation for "gestion des configurations".